# Define enum as the column names of table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to define an `enum` using a table's column names?

I have a `users` table defined as follows:

```sql
create table public.users (
  "id" serial not null unique primary key,
  "name" text not null check(length(name) > 1),
  "photo" text,
  "phone" text not null unique,
  "email" text not null unique,
  "bio" text,
  "socials" social[] not null
);
```

And then I want to define a `required_profile_fields` column in another table to be an `enum` containing only the column names in that `public.users` table:

```sql
create type profile_fields as enum('name', 'photo', 'email', 'phone');
create table public.orgs (
  "required_profile_fields" profile_fields[] not null check(array_length(required_profile_fields) > 0)
);
```

Is there a way that I can define that `profile_fields` as an `enum` from the column names in `public.users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
  SELECT
    format('CREATE TYPE profile_fields AS ENUM (%s)', 
            string_agg( DISTINCT quote_literal(column_name), ', ') )
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'users'
);
END 
$$
```

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that this only accesses the columns names from `public.users` (i.e. only tables in the `public` schema)? I'm using Supabase which defines an `auth.users` table that I don't want to include in this enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE (
  SELECT
    format('CREATE TYPE profile_fields AS ENUM (%s)', 
            string_agg( DISTINCT quote_literal(column_name), ', ') )
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'users'
);
END 
$$
```